# How to make Fungible Token visible in Near Wallet?

Tags: token, nearprotocol, wallet

I am currently working in a contract that has it's own fungible token.
I am able to see my fungible token balance using the `near-api-js`, using the `ft_balance_of` function like this:

```
const res = await walletConnection
        ?.account()
        .viewFunction(contract?.contractId || '', 'ft_balance_of', {
          account_id: currentUser?.accountId,
        })
```

Unhappily when I open my Near Wallet I don't see the fungible tokens there.
I click in `send` then `select asset`, but the only asset I see there is Near. There is also no way to search for the contract address, like we do with Metamask, for example.
My token does have metadata. That's how it looks like currently:

```
{
    "spec": "ft-1.0.0",
    "name": "QuiD",
    "symbol": "QD",
    "icon": "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 288 288'%3E%3Cg id='l' data-name='l'%3E%3Cpath d='M187.58,79.81l-30.1,44.69a3.2,3.2,0,0,0,4.75,4.2L191.86,103a1.2,1.2,0,0,1,2,.91v80.46a1.2,1.2,0,0,1-2.12.77L102.18,77.93A15.35,15.35,0,0,0,90.47,72.5H87.34A15.34,15.34,0,0,0,72,87.84V201.16A15.34,15.34,0,0,0,87.34,216.5h0a15.35,15.35,0,0,0,13.08-7.31l30.1-44.69a3.2,3.2,0,0,0-4.75-4.2L96.14,186a1.2,1.2,0,0,1-2-.91V104.61a1.2,1.2,0,0,1,2.12-.77l89.55,107.23a15.35,15.35,0,0,0,11.71,5.43h3.13A15.34,15.34,0,0,0,216,201.16V87.84A15.34,15.34,0,0,0,200.66,72.5h0A15.35,15.35,0,0,0,187.58,79.81Z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E",
    "reference": null,
    "reference_hash": null,
    "decimals": 18
}
```

I wonder what could be causing the Fungible Token not to show up automatically. Is there something wrong with my metadata? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 3):

In order for a user to own and transfer tokens they need to first register in the contract. This is done by calling storage_deposit and attaching 0.00125Ⓝ. This method also allows to pay for other users to register them.

near call  storage_deposit '{"account_id": "account-to-register"}' --accountId your-account --amount 0.00125

documentation page: https://docs.near.org/develop/relevant-contracts/ft

Answer (score 2):

Have you followed the [NEP-141 standard](https://nomicon.io/Standards/FungibleToken/Core#nep-141)?

Maybe you need to implement `ft_total_supply` as wells as the `ft_balance_of` function? Have a look [here](https://nomicon.io/Standards/FungibleToken/Core) for reference.

It looks like you are [using metadata](https://nomicon.io/Standards/FungibleToken/Metadata) for the fungible token, so you also need to implement the `ft_metadata` function. It's important that the names are the same as defined in the standard. That way, wallets, and marketplaces can call those specific interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Both of the answers before are correct but just to give you some context, NEAR has a few criteria that can be used to let its indexer pick up on a Fungible Token contract (you need at least one of this for it to work):

```
The wallet will consider contracts as fungible tokens if they meet any of the following conditions:

1. Any account makes a call to it with one of the following methods and the receiver_id property of the args is the user's account ID.

ft_transfer
ft_transfer_call
ft_mint

2. The bridge token factory account makes a call to it with the mint method with the user's account ID as the account_id property of the args.

3. The user's account ID calls a method named storage_deposit OR any method prefixed with ft_ on it.

The wallet will then make a view call to ft_balance_of on the considered contract and list it as a fungible token if it returns a value that is more than zero.
```

You can check under [Fungible Token Discover](https://github.com/near/near-wallet/blob/1cb459dcdb60e724c1a54b16f524ca80edbbf86b/packages/frontend/docs/FungibleTokenDiscovery.md) for more details.